# Powershell access to a variable in previous pipe

Tags: powershell

I created the following command for merge all csv files that matches with a filter inside a folder and outputs it into an outfile.

```
$mainPath="C:\\users\\myuser\\temp";
$mergeFilter="myfile.csv";
$outFile = "C:\\users\\myuser\temp\test.csv";
Get-ChildItem $mainPath -Recurse -Include $mergeFilter |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
    Import-Csv -Delimiter ';' |
    Select-Object *,@{Name='Date'; Expression={"$dummyvariable"}}; |
    Export-Csv $outFile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
```

My issue is that, I want to add an extra column when some CSV's are merged using a variable called $dummyvariable but I dont know where I have to initialize it in order to get the value in the Expression={"..."}. If I declare before in the pipeline it doesn't work (I need to do it higher on the pipe to get a directory name)

Do you know how I can declare this variable and recover on the pipe that starts with "Select-Object"?

Thanks in advance

Best Regards.

Jose

Comment: Debugging would be easier if you'd assign intermediate results into temp variables instead of piping everything to the next cmdlet.

Comment: As an aside: `\\ ` in PowerShell strings is always treated literally (two backlashes), which just happens to work with filesystem paths, but you should avoid it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking for the **commmon [`-PipelineVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-pipelinevariable) (`-pv`) parameter** (PSv4+), which stores a given cmdlet's current output object in a **variable that can be referenced in *script blocks* in *later pipeline segments***.

Here's a simplified example:

```bash
# Create sample input file.
@'
foo;bar
1;2
'@ > file.csv

# NOTE: -pv fileObj (same as: -PipelineVariable fileObj)         
#       stores (potentially each) `Get-Item` output object in var. $fileObj, 
#       accessible in script blocks later in the the pipeline.
Get-Item file.csv -pv fileObj |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | 
  Import-Csv -Delimiter ';' |
  Select-Object *, @{ n='Date'; e={ $fileObj.LastWriteTime } }
```

The above yields something like:

```bash
foo bar Date              
--- --- ----              
1   2   2/17/18 4:17:25 PM
```

That is, `-pv fileObj` made `Get-Item` store its current output object in variable `$fileObj`, which the last pipeline segment was able to reference in the property-definition script block.

**Note**:

- Do *not* prefix the variable name with `$` in the `-pv` / `-PipelineVariable` argument: the mere variable *name* must be passed (e.g. `fileObj`); only on *accessing* the resulting variable is `$` required (e.g. `$fileObj`).

Comment: This is fantastic, -PipelineVariable (note: no $ on reference definition) is very under used.  Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a `ForEach-Object` to specify `$dummyvariable` without affecting other elements of the pipeline.

```
$mainPath="C:\\users\\myuser\\temp";
$mergeFilter="myfile.csv";
$outFile = "C:\\users\\myuser\temp\test.csv";
Get-ChildItem $mainPath -Recurse -Include $mergeFilter |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
    Import-Csv -Delimiter ';' |
    ForEachObject {$dummyvariable = "..."} |
    Select-Object *,@{Name='Date'; Expression={"$dummyvariable"}}; |
    Export-Csv $outFile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
```

This is untested. You may need to specify that the properties need to be passed along to the next pipeline by doing this:

```
ForEachObject {$dummyvariable = "...";$_} |
```

My approach would be to break things down though as advised by [vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844062/powershell-access-to-a-variable-in-previous-pipe#comment84692650_48844062). Makes it easier to debug and to maintain.